# Azure API management redirect http requests to https

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

New to Azure API management. I have deployed an API with a custom domain. The https requests are working but how can I redirect http requests to https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use combination of Control flow and Return response policies to achieve http to https redirection.

```
<inbound>
...
<choose>
<when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Scheme.Equals("http"))">
<return-response>
<set-status code="302" reason="Requires SSL" />
<set-header exists-action="override" name="Location">
<value>@("https://" + context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host + context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path)</value>
</set-header>
</return-response>
</when>
</choose>
...
<base />
</inbound>
```

Reference: [Enforcing all requests to APIM over HTTPS](https://dipolimene.medium.com/enforcing-all-requests-to-apim-over-https-2e8f4b7e03e2)

Comment: This way a potential query string is left out. To redirect the complete url:
`<value>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().Replace("http://","https://"))</value>`